# Multiple wordpress sites using the same files?

Tags: wordpress

I want to automate the creation process. My idea is:

1- the client creates an account in my site
2- I confirms this account and creates one wordpress instalation to my client.
3- The client logs into the admin area and chooses one pre-fixed theme and fills the wordpress with content.

Ok. My doubts are related with the file structure to this project.

If I have 5 clients, can I use 5 different sql tables connected to just one wordpress archives directory?

See that would be 5 different sites with different themes and different databases using the same files.

Comment: You're simply describing one wp install with 5 diff authors that have access to their own posts *only*, which is set up via privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out wordpress multisite.  You may find that the functionality is already there, and all you have to do is unlock it.

A multisite build will allow each user to have a completely custom site, and if you want, you can theme all of the sites under the same theme.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network